# How to measure elapsed game time disregarding time the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, timing

I’d like to measure the time a user needs to complete a task, like in a game. This is straightforward: Get the `NSDate` of start and end, then compute the difference.

However, I want to disregard the time the app spends in background, like when a phone call comes in. How do I do that? An `NSTimer` is (more or less) an alarm clock. I need kind of a stopwatch.

I *could* set up an `NSTimer` to fire, say, every second, and count the seconds, then invalidate the timer when the app goes into background and reactivate it when the app reenters foreground—but this seems overkill.

Is there a simple approach that I overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

You have a game loop that will run in any SpriteKit game.

When the game is paused the game loop pauses.

So calculate the elapsed time in each loop and add to an accumulative time.

Comment: I‘m not using sprite kit. The "game" is advancing only on user input. There is a "game is running" state but no game loop other than the plain vanilla Cocoa event loop.

Comment: @JoeVölker in that case you could respond to the application did move to background notification. Don't treat the game as a single event but as a series of 1 or more events separated by things like pausing the game moving to the background etc... then measure the time for each event and add them together.